# How to use xlrd for writing an excel file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, module, xlrd

How can I write an excel file(xls/xlsx) using `xlrd` module alone?
I tried `from xlrd import xlsx`, but couldn't find anything that will really help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xlrd only reads excel files.  To write them, look up xlwt, xlutils, xlsxwriter, or openpyxl - all of these packages can write binary files excel can read.  Excel can also read csv files, which the `csv` package (included with Python) can write (and read).

Comment: The Xlrd and XlsxWriter formats are different object types and are not interchangeable, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38950636/1059398

Comment: Also, xlutils uses xlrd and xlwt, so it's not really a separate option.