# Modify a value in xlsx Excel file using xlrd and xlutils

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I want to modify a string in a xlsx file using xlrd and xlutils.

There were solutions, one from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957831/edit-existing-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-with-xlrd-and-xlwt) and other from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38XhSpmuXQw) for xls files.

**However, these solution works only for xls format. I tried using these for xlsx format but that corrupts the file.**

Are there solutions when using the xlsx file?
Or should I use other packages to solve this?

-Best Regards

Comment: I'd suggest openpyxl.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl

Comment: Yes, use `openpxyl` for xlsx files. This is also the advice of the developers of `xlrd` and `xlutils`: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-excel/P6TjJgFVjMI/g8d0eWxTBQAJ

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I will try the openpyxl right now!

Answer (score 1):

`xlutils` relies on `xlrd` (to read files) and `xlwt` (to write files) packages as [stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45915666/1059398).

`xlwt` can only write .xls formatted files.

For reading  .xlsx formatted files one should use `openpyxl` or `XLRD`.
For writing to .xlsx formatted files one should use `openpyxl` or `xlsxwritter`.

Alternatively, if you will be running the code on a machine that has Microsoft Excel installed, you might want to try `xlwings`.

**Gotcha:**  [According to jmcnamara](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38950636/1059398) `xlrd` and `xlsxwritter` formats are different object types, thus, despite the fact that both can be used on .xlsx files, one would need to write a translator to be able to write a `xlrd` formatted file using `xlsxwritter`.