# xlutils only works on xls, not xlsx?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlutils

I have an existing Excel workbook, `Workbook_A`. I'm creating an identical workbook, `Workbook_B`, and then insert a few values into some of the cells in the new workbook.

A simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

rb = open_workbook(Workbook_A)
wb = copy(rb)
s = wb.get_sheet(0)
s.write(row, col, value)
wb.save(Workbook_B)
```

`Workbook_A` can be an `xlsx` file here, but I must save it as an `xls` file, `Workbook_B.xls`. Otherwise the file becomes corrupt and impossible to open.

Is there a way to fix this? Can I use `xlutils` with `xlsx`, or isn't the module compatible with that Excel-format?

Is [`openpyxl` the solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44975855/2338750)

<sub>I'm not the first one to encounter [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957831/edit-existing-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-with-xlrd-and-xlwt#comment45427579_26958437), but I can't find a fix.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `xlutils` relies on `xlrd` (to read files) and `xlwt` (to write files), thus, the `save` function of `xlutils` actually using `xlwt`.

`.xlsx` is a newer and completely different file format (basically zipped xml files) from `.xls`. While `xlrd` has been upgraded to read `.xlsx` files , `xlwt` wasn't upgraded to *write* such files ([does xlwt support xlsx Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738904/does-xlwt-support-xlsx-format)).

Since `xlwt` [only writes older Excel (`.xls`) files](https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), passing a .xlsx extension doesn't change a thing. The underlying format is still `.xls` (and is seen as corrupt by MS Excel because it relies on the extension, not on contents, to decide how to open the file)

So, either use `openpyxl` to do what you want (drop `xlutils`, `xlrd`, `xlwt` entirely since you don't care about legacy `.xls` format), or save as a temporary `.xls` file using your current process, then read it back sheet by using `xlrd` and write back to `openpyxl`.

Depending on the complexity of your current code, you may choose between a full rewrite or a dirty workaround involving much more packages (but avoiding to rewrite the current code)